# Remove elements from Webview using Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, multithreading, webview

I want to remove the `header` of a `Webview` in an android App. I have found that it can be done programatically as:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(mUrl).get();
document.getElementsByClass("header").remove();
WebSettings ws = mWebView.getSettings();
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(mUrl, document.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

The problem is that when the above code is executed, I receive a `ThreadPolicyException`. I think the cause is that too much work on main Thread is executed. I knowe there is a solution, which is though considered to be "quick and dirty":

```
ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
```

The recommended solution is that the code should be excecuted in a Background Thread (or in an `AsyncTask`). When I try this however I receive also an Exception because of the call of methods on a `Webview` on a Thread other than the `UIThread` withe the message:

```
Calling View methods on another thread than the UI thread.; 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling View methods on another thread than the UI thread.
```

What is then the appropriate "clean" solution to this issue?

Comment: Also you can try downgrade target-api in AndroidMainfest and Build.gradle to minimum as possible. Because this exception appear in last api.

Answer (score 1):

Try insert your code inside `runOniThread`:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       ... your code
    }
});
```

In my case this work fine inside background Threads (run from Fragment).

*Add:*

Also may be best way is javascript-injection:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished( WebView view, String url) {

        // ... 
        webview.loadUrl( "javascript: { document.getElementByClass('header').remove(); }");
        // ...
    }
}


  webview.setWebViewClient( new MyWebViewClient());
```

Comment: It has not worked fotr me.Even if the above code is executed inside a Background task, it throws the same Exception: NetworkonMainThreadException.

Comment: I add comment to my answer